# The OnEndPage event and a table with a RowSpan

Tags: css, itext, html-table

I added the creation of a table cone page header in OnEndPage. In table I a RowSpan that is not printed, while the rest is.

```
table.WriteSelectedRows (0, -1, pageSize.GetLeft (25), pageSize.GetTop (10), cb);
```

If I remove the RowSpan prints!

Comment: Is the table complete? A possible cause for the table not to print could be the fact that you didn't complete the rows. Show us the code that creates the table. (Also: I'll correct the title of your question: you should never add content in `OnStartPage`)

Comment: Also: which version of iTextSharp are you using? Rowspan has really improved over the last year. If you're using an older version, that could explain your problem too.

Comment: The version is 4.1.6.0 iTextSharp. thanks

Comment: That version is totally unsupported. It shouldn't even be used in production anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use:

```
    public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
    {
        if (document.PageNumber != 1)
        {
            if (report.repeatHead) //ripete l'intestazione del report su tutte le pagine di stampa
            {
                repeatHead(writer, document);
            }
            else
            {
                if (document.PageNumber == 2) //ripete l'intestazione del report solo sulla second pagina dopo la copertina
                {
                    repeatHead(writer, document);
                }
            }                   
        }
    }

    public void repeatHead(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
    {
        //OnStartPage
        base.OnStartPage(writer, document);
        Rectangle pageSize = document.PageSize;

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
        //table.WidthPercentage = 100;
        table.TotalWidth = pageSize.Width - 50;
        table.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;

        //impostazione larghezza celle
        iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rect = PageSize.A4;
        float pageWidth = rect.Width;
        table.SetWidthPercentage(new float[] 
                { 
                    (float).70 * pageWidth ,
                    (float).30 * pageWidth,
                }, rect);

        //Cella nome banca
        table.AddCell(CellTest(report.banca, 1, 2));
        //Cella descrizione indagine
        table.AddCell(CellTest("Valore1", 0, 0));
        //Cella data apertura
        table.AddCell(CellTest("Data apertura:  " + DateTime.Now, 0, 0));
        //Cella descrizione
        table.AddCell(CellTest("Descrizione", 0, 0));
        //Cella data chiusura
        table.AddCell(CellTest("Data chiusura: " + DateTime.Now, 0, 0));

        table.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, pageSize.GetLeft(25), pageSize.GetTop(10), cb);
    }

    private PdfPCell CellTest(string value, int colSpan, int rowSpan)             
    {
        iTextSharp.text.Font font = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial");
        PdfPCell c = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(value, font));

        c.BorderWidthLeft = 1f;
        c.BorderWidthTop = 1f;
        c.BorderWidthRight = 1f;
        c.BorderWidthBottom = 1f;

        if (rowSpan != 0) { c.Rowspan = rowSpan; }
        if (colSpan != 0) { c.Colspan = colSpan; }

        return c;
    }

    public override void OnCloseDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
    {
        base.OnCloseDocument(writer, document);
        template.BeginText();
        template.SetFontAndSize(bf, 8);               
        template.SetTextMatrix(0, 0);
        template.ShowText("" + (writer.PageNumber - 1));
        template.EndText();
    }
```

Comment: Is this the code producing the wrong result? Then please edit it into your question instead of posting it as an answer. If this code turns out the correct result, please edit the answer to indicate what you changed to make things work.